# full screen rigid webpage with flexible divs

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

How to make a webpage **the size of the client device screen,** and make it **insensitive to the browser viewport size,** in a simple and **cross-browser** way ?

with **flexible divs** the size of the container **the size of the device screen**.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to find with a quick search...

You'll need javascript and use the `screen` object

[Specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen)

[Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: yeah thanx, I've seen those post just before ask :p. I try a lot of think. and it doesn't work. I need to replace this: html, body {

height:100%;
width: 100%;
    
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
}                                                                           By something like this                                                            document.style.width = screen.width+"px";
    document.style.height = screen.height+"px";            
    document.body.style.width = screen.width+"px";
    document.body.style.height = screen.height+"px";

Comment: You need to apply the width to the HTML element, you can get this in a few ways. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyQPRv) how to apply screen width and height. Find more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Comment: Also, be sure to include relevant code in your questions, you'll get better and quicker help :) [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)